# Level Shifting Arduino 5v to 1.8v

Tags: arduino, level-shifting, 5v

I am trying to level shift 5v from the Arduino to 1.8v. I have hooked up the level shifter as pictured below. However, I am not getting 1.8v from pin A1. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image: Sparkfun TXB0104 Level Shifter]

Comment: Where is the other ground going to?

Comment: All grounds are going back to the Arduino Ground. Even the ground that accompanies the 1.8v.

Comment: How is the level shifter physically connected to your circuit? You *have* soldered pins or wires to it, right?

Comment: I don't have it soldered yet. It is sitting on header pins plugged into a breadboard. Everything is wired up with jumper cables.

Comment: Do you have any load connected to the output of the level shifter? An important thing to remember is that the TXB010x ICs drive the output through a 4k resistor. So if you had a stronger load on the output you may see a much lower output voltage than you expect.

Comment: Maybe the connection is not solid between the header and the level shifter?

Comment: @MatzeStrawberrymaker that's a very good point, if that is a photograph of the actual device the Michael is using, then the pin headers aren't soldered! That would result in intermittent connections at best.

Comment: Thanks guys! I will solder the pins and get back to you guys. Is my use of the OE pin on the "a" side correct?

Comment: while power down or power up it should be connected to ground with an pulldown resistor, after that you connect it to 1.8v

Comment: I have soldered the pins and it resolved the issue! I learned that sitting a breakout board on some header pins on a breadboard does not provide a solid connection. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 3):

The answer was to solder the headers to the breakout board. Sitting a breakout out board on top of header pins plugged into a bread board will not provide a a solid connection between pins.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both the Arduino Ground and the 1.8 V circuits ground are connected to each other And the translator board ground.

Aside from that, have you verified that the arduino output is high with a multimeter? If both the ground and Arduino high work as expected, then it's possibly a bad or dead level shifter.

Comment: I have all grounds going to the same ground rail on my bread board. Everything is grounded back to the Arduino ground. I can definitely see the B1 Pin going to 5v when I set it to HIGH. However, Nothing is coming out of the A1 Pin.

Answer (score 0):

According to page 1 of TI's data sheet, the chip's OUTPUT ENABLE must be pulled low while VccA and VccB power up, and such doesn't seem to be the case in your circuit.

[image]

Comment: How do I achieve that? Do I wire both OE pins to Arduino Pins and do DigitalWrite(PIN, LOW)? Do I have to set the OE pins back to high at some point?

Comment: I don't see that as a requirement, it's more of a precaution against floating inputs on B causing unwanted state changes on A, resulting in errors or worse. Like clearing an output register to a known state when a microcontroller starts up.

Comment: If anything, a Resistor Capacitor of a second should be good enough

Comment: @Passerby: If they take the time and effort to single it out as a problem/possible problem and refer to it on the first page of the data sheet with a "should", then as far as I'm concerned it's a requirement since not doing it could result in exactly the kind of problem Michael Vo is experiencing.  I agree with the RC reset, although one second sounds like forever.

Comment: @MichaelVo: I think all the OE pins are wired together on the board with a solder link you can use to separate them as shown on the [schematic.](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/TXB0104_breakout.pdf)  I'm not sure your write 0/wait/write 1 scheme will work since I'm not sure if the arduino output port pin states are guaranteed during powerup, but Passerby's suggestion to use a passive RC delay should work. But maybe just soldering everything down will fix everything. What happened with that, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to shift in only one direction and only one pin? A Shottky diode and a resistor can be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get 1.8 volt output from GPIO of Arduino you can use a voltage divider circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the code you are using to write to the pin:

```
analogWrite(2,255);
```

This will apply a PWM signal with 100% duty cycle to **Digital Pin 2** - yet you have connected your level shifter to **Analogue Pin 1**.

The function `analogWrite` is used for controlling PWM capable pins - it has nothing to do with the Analogue Pins.

Try the following and see if it does what you expect

```
digitalWrite(A1,HIGH);
```

---

**Edit**

Never mind, I misread your question - it seems you were talking about A1 on the level shifter, not A1 on the Arduino. Apologies.